# Pegar elemento criado pelo DOM JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Bom. Eu estou tendo problema ao tentar pegar um elemento criado dinamicamente no DOM com JavaScript...
Eu crio o elemento através de uma função com o evento de click, porém eu não consigo acessar o elemento depois que ele foi criado. Por exemplo, eu quero que através do código ele retorne a lista de elementos que foram criados dinamicamente, porém o retorno é sempre vazio, eu queria saber o que eu preciso fazer para que seja retornado o NodeList dos elementos logo depois deles serem criados:

```js
let clickMe = document.querySelector('#clickMe');
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let item = document.querySelectorAll('.itemMarkup');

clickMe.addEventListener('click', () => {
    insertMarkup();
});

let insertMarkup = () => {
    let markup = `
        <a href="#" class="itemMarkup">item</a>
    `;

    container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
};

console.log(item); // retorna NodeList[] (vazio)
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">click-me</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Era só mudar de local o  `...electorAll('.itemMarkup')` vem zerado pq esta acessando a referência de algo que nem foi criado ainda. se mudar  o `...selectorAll('.itemMarkup')` abaixo do `insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);` pode resolver  .. todo código é carregado antes de clicar no botão.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Existem dois problemas:

- O `console.log(item)` só é chamado uma vez (assim que a página é carregada).

  - Então, quando a página é carregada sempre será 0, porque nem deu tempo de clicar no botão.
- O `let item = document.querySelectorAll('.itemMarkup')` pode ser uma copia.

  - Se você quer os dados atualizados, chame-o novamente.

Isso pode ser resolvido de várias formas, uma delas:

```js
let clickMe = document.querySelector('#clickMe');
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let item = document.querySelectorAll('.itemMarkup');

clickMe.addEventListener('click', () => {
  insertMarkup();
});

let insertMarkup = () => {
  let markup = `<a href="#" class="itemMarkup">item</a>`;
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);

  // Chama a função, sempre que adicionar
  exibirAdicionados();
};


// Não utilize o `item`:
let exibirAdicionados = () => {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.itemMarkup'));
}
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">click-me</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Você também pode usar o `MutationObserver` ou também pode usar o `Bind`, por exemplo:

```js
let clickMe = document.querySelector('#clickMe');
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let item = document.querySelectorAll('.itemMarkup');

clickMe.addEventListener('click', () => {
  insertMarkup();
});

let insertMarkup = () => {
  let markup = `<a href="#" class="itemMarkup">item</a>`;
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
};


// Inicie o observer
let observer = new MutationObserver((e) => {
  console.log(e[0].target.children);
});
observer.observe(container, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true });
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">click-me</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Uma solução rápida, valeu!